# Flex 4 - Load image from external XML file to spark DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have done my EmployeeDetails application. But now I want to include image on DataGrid. I tried to do it. But I got a warning message like "warning: unable to bind to property 'url' on class 'XML' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)".

My sample code:

```
  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var urlRequest:URLRequest;

        private var xmlData:XML;
        private var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        private function loadXML(event:Event):void
        {
            xmlData = new XML(event.target.data);
            var xmlList:XMLList = xmlData.Employee;
            employeeXMLList = new XMLListCollection(xmlList);
        }

        private function load():void
        {
            urlRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/demo/TextXmlFile.xml");
            urlRequest.contentType = "XML";
            urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);
            loader.load(urlRequest);
        } 

    ]]>
</fx:Script>        
<fx:Declarations>   
        <s:XMLListCollection id="employeeXMLList" filterFunction="xmlListCollectionFilterFun"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{employeeXMLList}" width="100%" height="500">
    <s:columns>
    <s:ArrayCollection>
    <s:GridColumn id="image" dataField="url" headerText="Employee">                     
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:GridItemRenderer>                                    
                    <s:Image source="{data.url}"/>
                </s:GridItemRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
   </s:GridColumn>
   </s:ArrayCollection>
   </s:columns>
   </s:DataGrid>
```

And my XML file is like

```
<Employee>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Id>234</Id>
    <DOB>1990/04/02</DOB>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <Designation>Project manager</Designation>
    <Department>Mobile</Department>
    <DOJ>2008/04/11</DOJ>
    <Experience>15</Experience>
    <Mobile>9999999999</Mobile>
    <Email>john.a@Sybrant.com</Email>
   <url>http://localhost/demo/images/ale.jpg</url>
</Employee>   

<Employee>
    <Name>Ram</Name>
    <Id>432</Id>
    <DOB>1985/07/23</DOB>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <Designation>Program manager</Designation>
    <Department>Testing</Department>
    <DOJ>2008/04/15</DOJ>
    <Experience>13</Experience>
    <Mobile>8967563423</Mobile>
    <Email>ram.a@Sybrant.com</Email>
    <url>http://localhost/demo/images/gthompson.jpg</url>
</Employee>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of warning use `ObjectProxy` Class which implements IEventDispatcher. That warning clearly shows object not aware of property changes. Means UI can't update automatically when data changes happened. More details [ObjectProxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectProxy.html)

Basically our itemRenderer data object should be implements `IEventDispatcher`. Becasue flex databind techniques works via events called PropertyChangeEvent. If given data is not implement IEventDispatcher then it will shows Warning: unable to bind to property 'url' on class 'XML' (class is not an IEventDispatcher).

Best practices for programming always use `Strongly Type object` the key here is VO pattern [Convert XML to VO](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/exercises/ex2_08.html)

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.IList;
        import mx.utils.ObjectProxy;

        private var urlRequest:URLRequest;

        private var xmlData:XML;

        private var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        [Bindable]
        public var employeeList:ArrayCollection;

        private function loadXML(event:Event):void
        {
            xmlData = new XML(event.target.data);

            var xmlList:XMLList = xmlData.Employee;

            var employeeObj:ObjectProxy;

            employeeList = new ArrayCollection();

            for each (var emp:XML in xmlList) 
            {
                employeeObj = new ObjectProxy();
                employeeObj.Name = emp.Name;
                employeeObj.Id = emp.Id;
                employeeObj.DOB = emp.DOB;
                employeeObj.gender = emp.gender;
                employeeObj.Designation = emp.Designation;
                employeeObj.Department = emp.Department;
                employeeObj.Experience = emp.Experience;
                employeeObj.Mobile = emp.Mobile;
                employeeObj.Email = emp.Email;
                employeeObj.url = emp.url;          

                employeeList.addItem(employeeObj);
            }               
        }

        private function load():void
        {
            urlRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/demo/TextXmlFile.xml");
            urlRequest.contentType = "XML";
            urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);
            loader.load(urlRequest);
        } 

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>   

</fx:Declarations>

<s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{employeeList}" width="100%" height="500">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayCollection>
            <s:GridColumn id="image" dataField="url" headerText="Employee">                     
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>                                    
                            <s:Image source="{data.url}"/>
                            <s:Label text="{data.Name}"/>
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

**Another ways :**

To get rid of warnings use `XML(data).url.toString()` instead of `data.url`.

**Updated**

Problem here `XML(data).url` returns XMLList instead of String so use like `XML(data).url.toString()`.

```
<s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{employeeXMLList}" width="100%" height="500">
<s:columns>
    <s:ArrayCollection>
        <s:GridColumn id="image" dataField="url" headerText="Employee">                     
            <s:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <s:GridItemRenderer>                                    
                        <s:Image id="img" source="{XML(data).url.toString()}" toolTip="Hey tooltip here" /> //Note here
                        <s:Label text="{XML(data).Name}"/>
                    </s:GridItemRenderer>
                </fx:Component>
            </s:itemRenderer>
        </s:GridColumn>
    </s:ArrayCollection>
</s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Already I tried this one "<s:Image source="{XML(data).url}"/>". But It was displayed nothing.

Comment: could you please tell me the url value is right in xml file? I mean, this is a right way?

Comment: just copy & paste url into browser addressbar if you able to see image then it is correct else not.let me know?

Comment: Answer updated please see and  source="{XML(data).url}" it should be source="{XML(data).url.toString()}".

Comment: yes. I got the answer for this "source="{XML(data).url.toString()}". And I got answer with warning message for your code. But we have to change source like this "source="{data.url.toString()}". Last question, which one is right and fast?

Comment: I didn't get any warning here.if you use like source="{data.url.toString()} you will get warning meaage.So you like XML(data).url.toString().Any how it never impact performance issue.Please accepts as answer with upvote.